# I find a tableview cannot scroll in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios11

I found my `UITableView` can't scroll in iOS 11, so I did some tests in the "cell for row" delegate method:

- when I set the `cell.userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, scrolling works
- When I set the `cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, it doesn't

My custom view is in `cell.contentView`, so I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Does your custom cell contains a scrollview, or a gesture recognizer ?

Comment: it not contain scrollview, but I add some gesture recognizer, I try to clean them, it not work

Answer (score 16):

I find the solution:

```
    self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

when I change it to YES, tableView can work like before

Comment: After a long day of tweaking stuff, this answer came as a sweet relief :D